# MongoDB, json class & dictionary member serializing

Tags: json, mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

Let's say I've got such a class:

```
class A
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Dict1 { get; set }
}
```

And I want it to be serialized to Json like that:

```
"A" : {"strKey1" : "strVal1", "strKey2" : "strVal2"}
```

instead of:

```
"A" : { "Dict1" : {"strKey1" : "strVal1", "strKey2" : "strVal2"}}
```

so to say, I'd like to skip generating the "Dict1" key.

Is it possible?

Alternatively, how to force serialization of "custom" dictionary members?
When I write my class like this:

```
class A : Dictionary<string, string>
```

they key/value pairs of the dictionary do not get serialized...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself - custom serialization.

Comment: Care to share the solution?